# Epson L210 printer is non recognised

Tags: 14.04, printing, scanner

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and have already downloaded and installed the driver for my Epson L210, but  the printer is not recognised. When printing any document, the L210 does not appear in the printer list.

Comment: Got the answer after installin the deb drivers, need to add priner after going to printers click on add (usb of printer should be connected to laptop) it will search automaticaaly ,hense proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Install printer driver packages:

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-all-enforce cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debconf ghostscript libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libc-bin libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libusb-1.0-0 lsb-base poppler-utils procps
```

Then use the printer with the application, `system-config-printer-gnome`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 and epson L210 scanner set up
This is what I did and hopefully I will work just fine for you.

Goto 
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=28880&DSCCHK=ec6ec9b0ae7d86aeadf2c0b88252dbe4149a9831

Accept it then download

`iscan-data_1.29.0-2_all.deb` (install via ubuntu software center)

`iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb` (install via ubuntu software center)

Install `xsane` scanning from ubuntu software center

Restart computer.